# Is there a way to append a string to an array of strings in swift from an IBAction of UISwitch in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building a Password Generator app, and I want to add the feature that the user can choose between generating a password with symbols in it such as:  "!", "@", "&", ect. I want to do that with a UISwitch.

The problem is that I have an array of strings inside of a function (Inside the function I have all the code the make the generator work). Just like showed in the following picture:

[image]

And I have an IBAction of UISwitch, I tried appending a string with an if statement. Just like in the following screenshot:

[image]

But it just does not work.
I am new to swift so could someone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hwy chris, please post your code ... as code. You want viewers who see your question to want to run and play with your code, and you can guarantee they won't bother to do that if you make it hard (e.g. by require them to transcribe text from an image).

Comment: Hi there, should I post all of the code or just the one that I'm having problems with?

Comment: @DevChris1314 move the `words` declaration out of your `generatePassword` method. It should be declared as an instance property of your view controller. Change its declaration to `var` and use `append(contentsOf: ["!", "@", "$", "&"])` method to append more than one element to your collection.

Comment: @DevChris1314 A minimal reproducible example, which cuts out the noise and focuses on the essence of your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Alexander you can simply type `[m r e]` in comment to post those links it would show as  [mre]. There is many other shortcuts you can check [Comment Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @LeoDabus Neat, TIL! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things. First, your `words` array is defined inside the `generatePassword` method. So it can only be used within that method. That's why you're getting the error when trying to access it from *another* method (`switchSymbols`).

To fix that, declare your `words` array as a class member.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var words = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    
    @IBAction func switchSymbols(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            words.append(contentsOf: ["!", "@", "$", "&"])
        }
        print(words)
    }
}
```

Now every method within this view controller can access that array.

Second, notice how I changed the `words` array to a `var` from a `let`. `let` means it's a constant. Member declared as `let` cannot be changed after later. So you won't be able to append elements to it. When you define it as a `var` (variable), you can.

Third, see that I'm using the `append(contentsOf:)`. The `append(_:)` method only adds a single element to an array. But in your code, you're adding another array directly to the `words` array. To add contents of one array to another array, you use the `append(contentsOf:)` method.